# Give a example of $(x_{n})$ such thatt it's limit $L$ is a cluster point of $(x_{n})$

Tags: real-analysis

Give a example of $(x_{n})$ such that it's limit $L$ is a cluster point of $(x_{n})$ but it's **not** true that $$\exists N\in \mathbb{N},\quad \forall n >N,\quad x_{n}≠L\ $$

Anyone could help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x_n=\begin{cases}0, & n \in 2\mathbb N\\ \dfrac{1}{n}, & n \in 2\mathbb N +1\end{cases}$$